# Active Admin NoMethodError Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

Im setting up active admin on my rails app. I ran the generator to create the user resource but when i click on the users link on the admin dashboard i get:

```
NoMethodError in Admin/users#index

Showing /Users/nelsonkeating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `city_id_contains' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::User:0x007fde92d69840>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: render renderer_for(:index)
```

I have no clue what is generating this or where the error is coming from.. Any ideas? Thanks! (please let me know if you need to see any other files)

Models:

```
user.rb

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   rolify

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :province_id, :city_id
  belongs_to :province
  belongs_to :city
```

province.rb

```
 class Province < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :cities
      has_many :users
    end
```

city.rb

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :province
  has_many :users
end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "date_of_birth"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.integer  "zipcode"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "status"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer  "province_id"
    t.integer  "city_id"
  end

 create_table "provinces", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

 create_table "cities", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "province_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end
```

Comment: I'm guessing the city_id_contains is a method that ActiveAdmin generates based on relationships your user model shares with something else. 

What other models do you have and what are their relationships?

Comment: @YuKagi  ok thanks! added the relevant models... the province/cities are loaded in via csv to populate select list (not sure if thats relevant)

Comment: Can you also post the relevant parts of your schema.rb?

Comment: @YuKagi there you go! thanks!

Comment: I'm not seeing a city model there. Do you have one, or are the aspects of a city in the user model?

Comment: its there.. at the bottom of the schema part.. see "create_table "cities", :force => true do |t|... " you sort of have to scroll down within the box

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12663/discussion-between-yukagi-and-nkeating)

Comment: i got it! In my user model i had both city and city_id fields... that confused active admin.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: And.. how did you fixed that ? Can you answer your question ?

Answer (score 6):

This question helped me solve my problem.   I had to read the comments to figure out how to solve it so I am providing the answer here:

If you have a model that contains a belongs_to relationship, Active Admin will not like it if you have a column name that matches your belongs to foreign key id column name.

For instance in this case your foreign key is 'city_id' but you also have a column named 'city'.   Active Admin doesn't like this.   And likewise it really doesn't make sense to have that column to begin with.   Since you will access the city through the relationship.

To fix this you should create a migration that removes the city column.

```
class RemoveCityFromUser < ActiveRecord::Migration    
  def up 
    remove_column :users, :city
  end
end
```