# What is the best way to model a restaurant menu, capable of future editing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I am creating a website with Active Admin to allow the owners future control over the menu.  If we are working on the lunch menu, I have structured the models as a section that has_many items shown below.

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :desc, :id, :name, :price
  belongs_to :section
end
```

Creating a "section" works fine in Active Admin, but I am receiving an error in when trying to create an "item".

Error:

```
NoMethodError in Admin/items#new
undefined method `section_id' for #<Item:0xb5460b44>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Judging from the requirements you described, there doesn't seem to be more than one way to model what you need.

Comment: The specific error you're seeing is because you don't have a ``section_id`` field in your ``items`` table.

Comment: Added a section_id to the items migration and then :section_id to attr_accessible in the class Item.  It works, thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of flexibility you should consider not creating categories as models but as mere attributes. Once you create all the classes(ex. LunchSection, DinnerSection, WineSection) it's impossible to create a new one without programmer's participation.

What I would go for is create following classes:

1. Menu - representing a menu as in a separate piece of paper (so there could be a wine menu and dish menu for ex.). The "type" of the menu should be designated only by name.
2. Group or Category is a container for diffrent dishes of the same type like lunch, dessert, wine... as wel, theres just one `Group` class and there's an instance for each single group
3. MenuItem (or simply Item) is any element of a menu, belonging to group or menu (this is a design decision - items should not belong to both menu and group because that would cause conflict if you wanted to get all items in a menu)

Comment: This is the closest I could find: [Active Admin NoMethodError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073642/active-admin-nomethoderror-error), but I don't think I can delete my "sections" column and still achieve the same result?

Comment: Updated the initial question.